# transition_time with shadow mark for only one geom / layer

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I believe the images below should be fairly self explanatory. When using `transition_time`, does anyone have an idea how to create a shadow mark for only one geom (for labelling)?

Any workarounds very welcome. In a normal world, I'd create two plots (the plot and the title), but I don't know how to use gganimate on such a combined plot, at least I don't find a solution with cowplot and patchwork (given that at least patchwork shares the same developer, I thought it could maybe work.)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

myfoo <- data.frame(time = 1:100, x = 1:100, y = 1)

p <- 
  ggplot(myfoo) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = time))

p_anim <- 
  p +
  transition_time(time) +
  shadow_mark()

animate(p_anim, height = 150, width = 250)
```

[image] The label in the bottom left should not have a shadow mark.

What I am looking for is something like the following:

```
p_title <- 
  ggplot(myfoo) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  labs(title = "{frame_time}")

p_title_anim <- 
  p_title +
  transition_time(time) +
  shadow_mark()

animate(p_title_anim, height = 150, width = 250)
```

[image] The interactive element from the title should be a plot annotation.

Comment: `shadow_mark(exclude_layer = 2)`?

Comment: @Z.Lin - I have posted your comment as an answer. I still hope you would post yourself, because you deserve this. I'll unaccept mine and accept yours. (Feel free to just copy my code including gif)

Comment: Thanks for the offer :) I really don't feel that I deserve credit for this one, since it's all in the manual, & I just happened to be reading through them for another question (which I still can't solve...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Z.Lin in her comment, here the solution with the `exclude_layer` argument in `shadow_mark()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

myfoo <- data.frame(time = 1:100, x = 1:100, y = 1)

p <- 
  ggplot(myfoo) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = time))

p_anim <- 
  p +
  transition_time(time) +
  shadow_mark(exclude_layer = 2)

animate(p_anim, height = 150, width = 250)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>